# Creating a new column that has the sum of multiple columns per row using data.table in R

Tags: r, sum, data.table

I have a data.table in R that's shown below:

[image]

I want to add a column that represents the sum of ace, bb, and statin for every row. So for the rows shown above, the new column would have the following values: 2,1,2,1,2

The name of the table above is `adherence`, I tried the following code to add the sum:

```
adherence[, total := sum(ace,bb,statin)]
```

but instead of calculating the sum per row, it calculates the sum of all three columns and gives me the table below:

[image]

How do I get the sum of the three columns per row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution. (Note that if any row contains a missing value, the row sum would be missing).

```
library(data.table)

adherence[, total := ace + bb + statin]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `sum` calculate the entire sum of the columns.  Instead, we need `rowSums` (assuming the input dataset as `data.table`, specify the columns to select in `.SDcols`, and apply the `rowSums` on the Subset of data.table (`.SD`)

```
library(data.table)
adherence[, total := rowSums(.SD, na.rm = TRUE),
     .SDcols = c("ace", "bb", "statin")][]
```

Or without specifying the `.SDcols`

```
adherence[, total := rowSums(.SD[, .(ace, bb, statin)], na.rm = TRUE)]
```